# P2P Cirrus connection Flash-client and HTML-client

Tags: javascript, html, flash, p2p, adobe-cirrus

In a network many examples of p2p (Cirrus) Flash text chat and games. 
Is it possible to connect with Cirrus two clients to exchange messages, one of which flash client and the other normal HTML (JavaScrip and PHP) without Flash?

Of course you can just put the flash-client on the side of the second user who when receiving messages from the first user to broadcast these messages to HTML (External Interface). But how to send messages from HTML forms to Flash SWF?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple my friend. You almost figured it out. Just create a button on the HTML form, that does not submit the form, but run a JavaScript function to read it, maybe JSON convert the data, and send it to the flash-client using an AS3 previously declared callback function, getElementByID().function, that by its ways, will send the data normally using flash.

Other question, do you know how to setup a P2P chat without usind any third parties service? I'd like to use flash to comunicate with people directly.. an exaple maybe? tks!
dulldusk@gmail.com